# Solving approach for a series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, series

I am having a great trouble on finding the solution of this series.

> index  1   2   3    4   5 
>   number 0   1   5   15   35

here say first index is an exception but what is the solution for that series to pick an index & get the number. Please add your Explanation of the solving approach.
I would also like to have some extra example for solving approach of other this kind of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approaches to solve a general series matching problem vary a lot, depending on the information you have about the series. You can start with reading up on [time series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

For this series you can easily google it and find out they're related to the binomial coefficients like [n!/(n-4)!/4!](http://oeis.org/A000332) . Taking into account i, it will be something like (i+3)!/4!/(i-1)!